# send buffer directly to a smartcard

Tags: java, smartcardio

I need to send a message to a smartcard. 
First of all, I sent it using gpshell in order to test the correctness and get an answer:

```
send_apdu_nostop -sc 0 -APDU 802A80B05F87410061DA7A1E2F02602A255063713FD657797063C6C7ACC12072F5340B1C0126A616BC66C65F49132EED10AE071DC661AA1333BEA92F67A5BEFFDFA7A0F31FC8B3D981105D1EF96B000FD90098C7FF031906A1018E0897C5DA580059AD2900                             Command --> 802A80B05F87410061DA7A1E2F02602A255063713FD657797063C6C7ACC12072F5340B1C0126A616BC66C65F49132EED10AE071DC661AA1333BEA92F67A5BEFFDFA7A0F31FC8B3D981105D1EF96B000FD90098C7FF031906A1018E0897C5DA580059AD2900
Wrapped command --> 802A80B05F87410061DA7A1E2F02602A255063713FD657797063C6C7ACC12072F5340B1C0126A616BC66C65F49132EED10AE071DC661AA1333BEA92F67A5BEFFDFA7A0F31FC8B3D981105D1EF96B000FD90098C7FF031906A1018E0897C5DA580059AD2900
Response <-- 604001544F50434F4E31392020202020000000FF00FF0000FF00020000000000000000FF5D11DCAD000000005D11DCAD005D1EF96B9000
```

With this result I was confident to replicate the behaviour in java using smartcardio.
The following is the code I wrote:

```java
    void testCard()
    {
        TerminalFactory factory = TerminalFactory.getDefault();
        List<CardTerminal> terminals;
        try {
            terminals = factory.terminals().list();
        } catch (CardException ex) {
            return;
        }
        CardTerminal cardTerm = terminals.get(0);
        Card card;
        try {
            card = cardTerm.connect("T=0");
        } catch (CardException ex) {           
            return;
        }
        CardChannel cach = card.getBasicChannel();
        ResponseAPDU r;
        try {
            CommandAPDU ca = new CommandAPDU(new byte[]{(byte)0x80,(byte)0x2A,(byte)0x80,(byte)0xB0,(byte)0x5F,(byte)0x87,(byte)0x41,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x61,(byte)0xDA,(byte)0x7A,(byte)0x1E,(byte)0x2F,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x60,(byte)0x2A,(byte)0x25,(byte)0x50,(byte)0x63,(byte)0x71,(byte)0x3F,(byte)0xD6,(byte)0x57,(byte)0x79,(byte)0x70,(byte)0x63,(byte)0xC6,(byte)0xC7,(byte)0xAC,(byte)0xC1,(byte)0x20,(byte)0x72,(byte)0xF5,(byte)0x34,(byte)0x0B,(byte)0x1C,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x26,(byte)0xA6,(byte)0x16,(byte)0xBC,(byte)0x66,(byte)0xC6,(byte)0x5F,(byte)0x49,(byte)0x13,(byte)0x2E,(byte)0xED,(byte)0x10,(byte)0xAE,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x1D,(byte)0xC6,(byte)0x61,(byte)0xAA,(byte)0x13,(byte)0x33,(byte)0xBE,(byte)0xA9,(byte)0x2F,(byte)0x67,(byte)0xA5,(byte)0xBE,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xDF,(byte)0xA7,(byte)0xA0,(byte)0xF3,(byte)0x1F,(byte)0xC8,(byte)0xB3,(byte)0xD9,(byte)0x81,(byte)0x10,(byte)0x5D,(byte)0x1E,(byte)0xF9,(byte)0x6B,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x0F,(byte)0xD9,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x98,(byte)0xC7,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x19,(byte)0x06,(byte)0xA1,(byte)0x01,(byte)0x8E,(byte)0x08,(byte)0x97,(byte)0xC5,(byte)0xDA,(byte)0x58,(byte)0x00,(byte)0x59,(byte)0xAD,(byte)0x29,(byte)0x00});   
            r = cach.transmit(ca);           
        } catch (CardException ex) {            
            return;
        }
    }
```

When the code runs I always get the error 0x6E00 which means: "Class not supported".

Reading the javadoc of [transmit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CardChannel.html#transmit(javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU)) I understand that "The CLA byte of the command APDU is automatically adjusted to match the channel number of this CardChannel."

I suspect that for some reasons the class byte was changed somehow and for that reason the card answers with the error.

Is there any way to send directly the message to the card in java?

Comment: Which card are you using? And documentation for that card?

Comment: Thank you, for your interest in this thread but the question is not related to the card, the question is about how to obtain the same behaviour showed in gpshell using java.

Comment: Yes, see what I posted and see if it can help you in any way. Since I don't have a card, can't explore it practically and test the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems that using "T=0" is not a suitable way to send the second command. Using "T=1" or "*" solve the problem.
The correction is the following:

```java
card = cardTerm.connect("T=1");
```

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE: I have not worked with Smart cards and don't have one to validate this answer. But it may point you in the right direction**

If you look at the source code of `gshell`. For sending the `APDU` it reads it like below

```c
 else if (_tcscmp(token, _T("-APDU")) == 0)
        {
            token = strtokCheckComment(NULL);
            if (token == NULL)
            {
                _tprintf(_T("Error: option -APDU not followed by data\n"));
                rv = EXIT_FAILURE;
                goto end;
            }
            else
            {
                pOptionStr->APDULen = ConvertStringToByteArray(token, APDULEN, pOptionStr->APDU);
            }
        }
```

https://github.com/sigma/globalplatform/blob/7f1c8669c5991a60b6fada9b1187d2ee6d040223/gpshell/src/gpshell.c#L1648

So what you passed is complete APDU command

```c
if (platform_mode == PLATFORM_MODE_OP_201)
{
    status = OP201_send_APDU(cardContext, cardInfo,
                            (optionStr.secureChannel == 0 ? NULL : &securityInfo201),
                            (PBYTE)(optionStr.APDU), optionStr.APDULen,
                            recvAPDU, &recvAPDULen);
}
```

Which in turn goes to

https://github.com/sigma/globalplatform/blob/7f1c8669c5991a60b6fada9b1187d2ee6d040223/globalplatform/src/connection.c#L202

```c
OPGP_ERROR_STATUS OPGP_send_APDU(OPGP_CARD_CONTEXT cardContext, OPGP_CARD_INFO cardInfo, GP211_SECURITY_INFO *secInfo, PBYTE capdu, DWORD capduLength, PBYTE rapdu, PDWORD rapduLength) {
    OPGP_ERROR_STATUS errorStatus;
    OPGP_ERROR_STATUS securityStatus;
    OPGP_ERROR_STATUS(*plugin_sendAPDUFunction) (OPGP_CARD_CONTEXT, OPGP_CARD_INFO, PBYTE, DWORD, PBYTE, PDWORD);
    BYTE apduCommand[261];
    DWORD apduCommandLength = 261;
    int i=0;

    OPGP_LOG_START(_T("OPGP_send_APDU"));
    plugin_sendAPDUFunction = (OPGP_ERROR_STATUS(*)(OPGP_CARD_CONTEXT, OPGP_CARD_INFO, PBYTE, DWORD, PBYTE, PDWORD)) cardContext.connectionFunctions.sendAPDU;
```

So I think an extra `cardContext` is required to be appended in your command, which is currently not there

See few implementations also and see if you can make out the bytes

https://github.com/handywings/tutorial_hdw_mc/blob/a1dceae1b243b0c79dda5c73218e3a9ff84c259c/src/main/java/com/hdw/mccable/utils/ThaiLandIdCard.java

https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076450/how-to-write-a-java-card-applet--a-developer-s-guide.html

https://github.com/arg3s/ClassAttendanceMaster/blob/a368b07e9b94bd387f91d7d6f57f12e402d58b32/src/main/java/com/classattendancemaster/SmartCard/SmartcardConnector.java

Comment: thank you, I will try to follow your suggestion and I'll look at gpushell first. But even if I find the correct bytes to send, I still won't know how to do it in java.